# Values in matrix visual misaligned

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

The values in matrix visual are misaligned. Those where measure contains DIVIDE function are right aligned, while those with COUNTROW function are all center aligned. Is this normal behaviour and if so how do I make them all consistent?

[image: Misaligned matrix values]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to format tab and select specific column and select the alignment you want

[image]